# Wrap code in a function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

> Write a function 
>       Hi, **name** You are **current age** this year.

So far I have this:

```
from datetime import date
p = current_year = date.today().year

name = raw_input("enter your name")
y = raw_input("enter ur month of birth")
z = raw_input("enter your year of birth")

current_age =(int(p)-int(z))

print current_age
print("Hi,", name, " you are" , current_age, " years old this year!"
  "Here's a bouquet of flowers for you!")
```

This code works but I am trying to turn it into a function. Can anyone help?

```
from datetime import date
p = current_year = date.today().year

def bday_wish(name,y,z):
    current_age =(int(p)-int(z))

print current_age
print("Hi,", name, " you are" , current_age, " this year!")
```

Comment: Define a function with `def` and use `name`, `y`, and `z` as parameters.

Comment: A comment: you are printing how many years old the person is *or will be* this year. I guess that might be what you want, hence the text "years old this year". I wouldn't call that "current age", though.

Comment: Why would you ask for month if you're not going to use that information? And besides that...why not ask for their exact date of birth? Because month and year is still not enough information to tell how old someone is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take the personal information as arguments, you can use this:

```
from datetime import date

def display_birthday_wishes(name, month, year):
    p = current_year = date.today().year
    current_age = (int(p)-int(year))

    return "Hi, " + name + ". You are " + str(current_age) +\
    " years old this year! Here's a bouquet of flowers for you!"

print display_birthday_wishes("David", 4, 1998)
```

However, if you still want to get the information using `raw_input`, you can use this:

```
from datetime import date

def display_birthday_wishes():
    name = raw_input("enter your name")

    current_year = current_year = date.today().year
    year_born = raw_input("enter your year of birth")

    current_age = (int(current_year)-int(year_born))

    month_born = raw_input("enter your month of birth")


    return "Hi, " + name + ". You are " + str(current_age) +\
    " years old this year! Here's a bouquet of flowers for you!"

print display_birthday_wishes()
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function called `display_birthday_wishes`. Inside it place the code you want to run, call the function when you need it.

```
from datetime import date

def display_birthday_wishes(): #define the function, no arguments passed in
    p = current_year = date.today().year

    name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    y = raw_input("Enter the month you were born in: ")
    z = raw_input("Enter your year of birth ")

    current_age =(int(p)-int(z))

    print current_age
    print"Hi,", name, "you are" , current_age, "years old this year! Here's a bouquet of flowers for you!"

display_birthday_wishes() #call the function
```

More on defining functions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date


name = raw_input("enter your name")
y = raw_input("enter ur month of birth")
z = raw_input("enter your year of birth")

def display_birthday_wishes(name, month, year):
    p = current_year = date.today().year
    current_age =(int(p)-int(year))

    print current_age
    print("Hi,", name, " you are" , current_age, " years old this year!"
      "Here's a bouquet of flowers for you!")

display_birthday_wishes(name, y, z)
```